# Find first object with relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Are there any methods or better ways to find first object in collection that has associated objects than iterate and `break`?

```
collection.each {|item| break item if item.the_associations.present?}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

['find' for enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
collection.to_a.find{ |i| i.associations.present? }
```

Or you could join the associations and take the first e.g.

```
People.joins(:children).first
```